# how to return inputted value when no value is found in list comprehension Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a function which finds the pair of a character inputted, in a list, that is also inputted.

```
findc :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Char
findc x list = head[ if null c then x else c| (n,c) <- list, x == n ]
```

if no letter is found in list that matches input, the function is meant to return the value inputted. The above code doesn't work as null is invalid type for c.
the following code only works for when a letter is found:

```
findc :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Char
findc x list = head[ c| (n,c) <- list, if x == n then c==c else c==x]
```

```
 > findc 'B' [('A','F'), ('B','G'), ('C','H')]
'G'
```

but when not found it doesn't work, as it returns empty list rather than the inputted char.

How can i return the inputted char if char not found in list?

Answer (score 2):

Your first code contains the right kind of ideas but in a wrong order. You can put the if expression outside of the comprehension:

```
findc :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Char
findc x list = 
  let filtered = [ c | (n,c) <- list, x == n ]
  in if null filtered then x else head filtered
```

But it is more idiomatic to use pattern matching instead of an if expression and `null` and `head`:

```
findc :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Char
findc x list = 
  case [ c | (n,c) <- list, x == n ] of
    [] -> x
    (y:_) -> y
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already a function in Prelude that does most of what you want:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

With this, all you have to do is call `lookup` and then distinguish the `Just` and `Nothing` cases:

```
findc :: Eq a => a -> [(a, a)] -> a
findc goal table = case lookup goal table of
  Nothing -> goal
  Just subst -> subst
```

But of course there is also a function for unwrapping a Maybe with a default value:

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
```

Combining these two, we get a simple definition:

```
findc :: Eq a => a -> [(a, a)] -> a
findc goal table = fromMaybe goal (lookup goal table)
```

If you are so inclined, you can play some code golf here, by noting that the `table` argument is just sorta handed from `findc` into its implementation at the end, which you can make implicit:

```
findc :: Eq a => a -> [(a, a)] -> a
findc goal = fromMaybe goal . lookup goal
```

Finally, the truly depraved might try to eliminate the `goal` argument, which is an interesting exercise, but does not yield a very readable result:

```
findc :: Eq a => a -> [(a, a)] -> a
findc = liftA2 (.) fromMaybe lookup
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a list comprehension, you could use `Data.List.find`. This function returns a `Maybe` type, which you can pattern match on to either return the character provided, or the corresponding character from the list of tuples.

```
import Data.List

findc :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Char
findc ch lst =
  let match = find ((ch ==) . fst) lst
  in
    case match of
      Nothing -> ch
      Just (_, v) -> v
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `find`. It looks like it's a generalization of `Prelude.lookup` (generalizing both from `[]` to `Foldable` and from `Eq` to an arbitrary predicate), but we don't need the generalization, do we?

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of doing this:

```
 data Result a = Found a | NotFound a deriving Show

 lst = [('A','F'), ('B','G'), ('C','H')]

 findc :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Result Char
 findc x [] = NotFound x
 findc x (n:ns)
    | x == fst n = Found (snd n)
    | otherwise = findc x ns

 main = do
    print $ findc 'B' lst    -- Found 'G'
    print $ findc 'D' lst    -- NotFound 'D'
```

I created a new data structure for the result, either `Found value` or `NotFound value`. This prevents the problem where we have a list including ('B','B'), which returns the search term even though the search term has successfully matched.

Comment: This data type is a cute idea. It's a bit of a bummer, though, that it's too "large": it can represent results that should be impossible. For example, `findc 'A' xs` can never return `NotFound 'B'`, but there is room in the type for that nonsense result. I think this argues for just returning `Maybe a` instead of using `Result a`: for every value `ret :: Maybe a` and every input `x :: a`, there is some `xs :: [(a, a)]` such that `findc x xs = ret`. This seems like a nice property, in that there are no cases you know you can ignore when pattern matching.

Comment: @amalloy: I would agree that using the Maybe monad to return Just value or Nothing might be best - indeed that is the way that I would code it - but here the opening post required the match if one is found, or the original value if not. Maybe doesn't work, because the failure result is Nothing ,and doesn't contain the original value. If you then 
pattern match on Maybe to replace Nothing with the original value you have thrown away the Maybe result. Cute or not, the requirements drove me to creating a new data type. Either is also abusable. And if it made you smile, why not?